# Django: image not saved when using CreateView with a HTML template

Tags: python, django

To wrap some text around one of my CreatView classes I use a HTML template to wrap the form. However, when using this template everything works as expected except that the image passed to the ImageField of the form is not saved. Commenting out the the line where the template of the CreateView is set solves the problem. But I would like to use the template to have the option to show more on the page than just the form.
How does the logic of the form change when wrapping it into a template?

**views.py**

```
class PieceInstanceCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = PieceInstance
    fields = ['version', 'piece_image', 'status']
    # commenting out the below line makes the form save the image
    template_name = 'pieceinstance_create.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.piece = Piece.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return super(PieceInstanceCreate, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('piece-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk']})
```

**pieceinstance_create.html**

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Add a Version</h1>

  <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As django docs [mention](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files-to-a-form),  for file uploads to work, you need to set [`enctype="multipart/form-data"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/enctype)  form attribute in the template :

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```